# PetaPoco, specifically schotime's, 'no mapping exists to a known provider type'

Tags: petapoco

I'm using a fairly old version of PetaPoco from https://github.com/schotime/PetaPoco - it's basically vanilla with support for multi-primary key columns. Decided it was time to upgrade. Grabbed the newest version from the schotime link just mentioned, dumped it into my project, and immediately had failures with code structured like so:

```
    class Program
{
    public class AggregateObject
    {
        public int aoId { get; set; }

        [PetaPoco.Ignore]
        public Object1 o1 { get; set; }

        [PetaPoco.Ignore]
        public Object2 o2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Object1
    {
        public int o1Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class Object2
    {
        public int o2Id { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var db = new Database("test");

        var test = db.Fetch<AggregateObject, Object1, Object2, AggregateObject>(
            (ao, o1, o2) =>
                {
                    ao.o1 = o1;
                    ao.o2 = o2;
                    return ao;
                },
            "SELECT 1 AS aoId, 2 AS o1Id, 3 AS o2Id WHERE 1 <> @start AND 2 <> @end",
            new
                {
                    start = 5,
                    end = 5
                });
    }
}
```

Which throws this error

```
No mapping exists from object type <>f__AnonymousType0`2[[System.Int32, mscorlib,
Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] to a known managed provider native type.
```

for each parameter I'm attempting to pass in (in this case, System.Int32, System.Int32).

Did something change in the way parameters are passed in via this method? Very confused at the error.

Comment: Nothing has changes on those methods. It looks like you are calling it incorrectly though. Could you please provide an example that actually compiles?

Comment: Thought that one would, sorry. I've included a better example that will generate the issue without actually hitting any tables. This code works with the version of PetaPoco in Nuget and returns a result; with the latest version I grabbed from your PetaPoco github page, it errors with the exception I gave above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed in 4.0.3.12 available to download here:
https://github.com/schotime/PetaPoco/downloads